# Generating missing values in a discontinuous table

Tags: perl, sed, awk

A file contains several tables. Each table has three columns separated by tabs.

The first column contains the serial number which is not continuous. I want to print missing serial number with second and third column with 0 0.

**input file**

```
Pos freq catagory
    13    1       4
    14    2       3
    17    5       2
    20    3       2 <<<<<
    21    1       4
    25    1       4
Pos freq catagory
    10    1       4
    12    2       3
    13    5       2
    14    3       2 <<<<<
    15    1       4
```

**output file**

```
Pos freq catagory
    13    1       4
    14    2       3
    15    0       0
    16    0       0
    17    5       2
    18    0       0
    19    0       0
    20    3       2 <<<<<
    21    1       4
    22    0       0
    23    0       0
    24    0       0
    25    1       4
Pos freq catagory
    10    1       4
    11 0 0 
    12    2       3
    13    5       2
    14    3       2 <<<<<
    15 1 4
```

Could you please help me to do it in Perl, sed, or awk?

Comment: Have you written any code so far that you could post?

Comment: There are no tabs in the data that you posted. Are there really spaces before the numbers in the first column? Are the `<<<<<` there in the real data?

Comment: After a tab one row has <<<<< symbol. there is tab between third column and symbol. I am writing a perl program for it.

Comment: Are there really spaces before the numbers in the first column? It is important to get the formatting of your data correct, and it is impossible to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are interested in a coreutils+sed solution:

```
$ join -a2 -j1 -t $'\t' input_file <(seq 13 25) | sed 's/^[^[:space:]]*$/&\t0\t0/'
13      1       4
14      2       3
15      0       0
16      0       0
17      5       2
18      0       0
19      0       0
20      3       2
21      1       4
22      0       0
23      0       0
24      0       0
25      1       4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '!p{p=$1-1}++p<$1{for(p;p<$1;p++)print p,0,0}7' file 
13  1   4
14  2   3
15  0   0
16  0   0
17  5   2
18  0   0
19  0   0
20  3   2
21  1   4
22  0   0
23  0   0
24  0   0
25  1   4
```

Answer (score 1):

This Perl program is unnecessarily long because it tries to use the spacing in the original file in the filled data lines. It also gets things wrong if the first field is fixed length with leading spaces.

Yes, I know It is silly to write software that guesses the proper specification.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq;

while (<>) {
  if ( / ( (\s*) (\d+) ) /x ) {
    if (defined $seq) {
      printf "%s%d\t0\t0\n", $2, $_ for $seq+1 .. $3-1;
    }
    $seq = $3;
  }
  else {
    $seq = undef;
  }
  print;
}
```

**output**

```
Pos freq catagory
    13    1       4
    14    2       3
    15  0 0
    16  0 0
    17    5       2
    18  0 0
    19  0 0
    20    3       2 <<<<<
    21    1       4
    22  0 0
    23  0 0
    24  0 0
    25    1       4
Pos freq catagory
    10    1       4
    11  0 0
    12    2       3
    13    5       2
    14    3       2 <<<<<
    15    1       4
```

Comment: @FIROZ: No, it's not, it's a very poor program. I chose to answer like this because you would not answer my questions or describe your data properly. I didn't expect to be taken seriously. Please put some of your *real* data on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so that I can improve my code